# Battery saver feature prevents WorkManager to be executed

Tags: android, android-workmanager, battery-saver

Devices such as Huawei, Xiaomi, some Samsung models, or most of the devices I know that has MIUI, EMUI in their system has by default turned on battery saver features and automatic "optimizations". Recently I've created an important worker but my device (Huawei P20 Lite) has this built-in feature which prevents the job from running (it even shows that the system blocked the execution), unless I go to that panel and let the app execute on background by myself.

On a production environment we can't tell the users to go to this menu and let us run on background (simply because we don't know how many variations of these battery saver features), the app itself doesn't run on background on most cases. However, this worker still should execute because the task is pretty important.

Two questions:

1) For a rough estimate, how much percentage of devices will prevent a work manager task to be executed?

2) Can any workarounds be applied for this situation?

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please, a file bug on Google issuetracker under this component:
[Android Public Tracker -> Device-Specific App Issues](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=735851&template=1348774).
This seem a CDD violations and the bug will help Google explaining to the OEMs what needs to be fixed.

I've seen that there's a library that tries to handle ([Autostarter](https://github.com/judemanutd/AutoStarter)), across different devices, opening the right setting. **This is just a workaround**.
The best course of action is to report the issue, but this will probably request some time to be fixed and the user will need to update the OS.